# What genre have the games like Travian?

Tags: travian, genre-identification

The Travian itself describes it as realtime strategy. But looking at the classic one like Dune 2 or StarCraft, Travian is definitely something else.

The Wikipedia has nice [list of categorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_genre) but is it missing one for Travian.

For clarification the question is about realtime not the strategy part.
For example most of the shooter games are realtime. Realtime usually means quick decisions and some dexterity skills. Travian and ogame lacks of both.

Comment: It's definitely a MMO real-time strategy, why do you think it's not?

Comment: I call them "Ogame-like" or "Chronophage games"

Comment: I like Chronophage games because when I think ogame or travian I dont think strategy, I think TIMERS FOR EVERY SINGLE THING.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travian#:%7E:text=Travian%3A%20Legends%20is%20a%20persistent,%22Travian%22%20by%20Gerhard%20M%C3%BCller.) lists it as

> [...] a persistent, browser-based, massively multiplayer, online
> real-time strategy game developed by the German software company
> Travian Games. It was originally written and released in June 2004
> as "Travian" by Gerhard Müller.

Looking at what that genre evolved into, Clash of Empires, they say it's an MMO game. Which doesn't mean much, just it's multiplayer and online.

If I had to put down a category, I would say it's a browser-based, timer-based, MMO Strategy game. Even if such a category doesn't exist.

*opinion : And really, at the end of the day, classifying games by solid genra becomes harder and harder every year. Games are not usually staying in their lanes anymore, and often go and pickup things from other games or even creating new types of themselves.

Comment: About the last point, games usually start in one genre and develop into a few other genres just to appeal to as many people as possible and crank up the sales. Travian is a good example if you look at the development over the years.